# Understanding mRNA vaccine for COVID

Tags: coronavirus, mrna, vaccine

As I've learned, mRNA helps us to produce virus spikes proteins to induce learning of the immune system.

But then, I remember to have read that the coronavirus has some trick to pretend to be "food" to our cells, that is it has some lipid element. So it can entry the cell easily. But this was not same part as the spike protein, right? (otherwise it would have been contradictory with the mRNA approach?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it wrong. Coronaviruses are part of a family of viruses that are called "enveloped viruses". These all have an "envelope" comprised of a lipid layer derived from the host cell as the virion exits. The envelope is distinct from the spike. The spike protein is produced by the virus during replication and is not found naturally in a host cell.

This does not pretend to be "food" at all, but it can help evade host immune responses by hiding the other virion capsid proteins.

Comment: thx this was the missing bit if information